# Подмена базового класса в сложившейся архитектуре классов

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

Имеется базовый класс (предположим, Window), у которого огромное число классов-потомков (BlackWindow, TransperentWindow, ...).

Предположим, что я хочу добавить в архитектуру класс BorderedWindow, который перегружает пару виртуальных функций родительского класса Window. И далее я хочу, чтобы все имеющиеся классы-потомки могли создаваться как от Window, так и от BorderedWindow.

Проблему можно проиллюстрировать следующим кодом:

```
class Window
{
    public virtual Rectangle ClientArea()
    {
        return new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 50);
    }
}

class BlackWindow : Window
{
    public BlackWindow(Window window) { ... }
}

class BorderedWindow : Window
{
    public overide Rectangle ClientArea()
    {
        return new Rectangle(5, 5, 110, 60);
    }
}

Window window = new Window();
BorderedWindow borderedWindow = new BorderedWindow();
new BlackWindow(window).ClientArea();                // Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 50), ОК
new BlackWindow(borderedWindow).ClientArea();        // Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 50), FAIL!
```

В целом, здесь можно применить паттерн Декоратор. Но этого делать не хочется, так как последуют существенные изменения классов-потомков. Придётся для каждой функции класса Window писать функцию-"обёртку" в каждом классе-наследнике. Для десятка функций и десятка классов объём кода вырастает драматически.

Как можно исправить ситуацию?

Answer (score 3):

Почему бы тогда не «Стратегия»? Вместо довольно неудобного наследования переходите на прогрессивную композицию. Пусть любой из классов получает `ClientStrategy` как часть конструктора.

```
interface IClientAreaStrategy { Rectangle ClientArea { get; } }

class DefaultClientAreaStrategy : IClientAreaStrategy
{
    Rectangle clientArea = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 50);
    public Rectangle ClientArea { get { return clientArea; } }
}

class BorderedClientAreaStrategy : IClientAreaStrategy
{
    Rectangle clientArea = new Rectangle(5, 5, 110, 60);
    public Rectangle ClientArea { get { return clientArea; } }
}

class Window
{
    protected readonly IClientAreaStrategy clientAreaStrategy;
    public Rectangle ClientArea
    {
        get { return clientAreaStrategy.ClientArea; }
    }

    public Window(IClientAreaStrategy clientAreaStrategy)
    {
        this.clientAreaStrategy = clientAreaStrategy;
    }
}

class BlackWindow : Window
{
    public BlackWindow(Window window) : base(window.ClientStrategy)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

(Кстати, у нужно ли наследование для BlackWindow? Возможно, вам снова нужна композиция?)

---

Для конкретно этого случая вам не нужен целый интерфейс `IClientAreaStrategy`, а просто `Func<Rectangle>` или даже просто `Rectangle`. Но в более сложном случае понадобится интерфейс.